# How to write <?php into a answer in Stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I tried to answer a question and putted:
"< ? php" (no blanks between it) into a answer here in stackoverflow.
But it does not work; i read about the advanced formatting but did not find the hint or explanation how to solve this.

Surely someone will know this.

Comment: Don't know about the downvote. Backtick on my keyboard is at the top left, next to the `1`

Comment: What is backtick: this ` or this ´

Comment: Try it. Preferrably in the sandbox http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox

Comment: What prevented you from reading the Formatting FAQ? Help on formatting is provided _right there next to the input box_.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php test(); ?>
```

Highlight and select code formatting works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Surround this with the symbol: `

Answer (score 0):

simply select the code and then press `ctrl + k`